# Accessing variables of a dynamic form

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating a form with `cfloop` and need to access each variable individually when submitting the form.  I need to use the selected entries of the form in a loop that will add my selections to a database.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">     
   <input type="hidden" name="isPost" value="1">
   ...
   <cfoutput>
   <cfloop query="client_admin_surveys">
      <input type="text" size="35" name="surveyID" id="surveyID" value="#id#">
      <input type="text" size="35" name="surveyName" id="surveyName" value="#name#">
      <input type="checkbox" name="amplify" id="amplify">          
      <input type="checkbox" name="enchance" id="enchance">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pacify" id="pacify">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pacifyUrgent" id="pacifyUrgent">
   </cfloop>
   </cfoutput>
   ...
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After posting the form, the results group all of my selections because I have the same "name" for my form elements. I tried adding an `i` count next to each name to make it different but then I got a bit confused about how to process the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started down the correct path when you added the counter - go back and add that, something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="amplify#client_admin_surveys.currentRow#" id="amplify">
```

Would work.

I also sometimes like to add a form field for the 'counter' on the processing page

```
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="#client_admin_surveys.recordCount#" />
```

Then on the processing page, you can loop over the counter and  access the form fields using bracket notation

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.counter#" indexd="i">
    <cfset thisAmplify = form["amplify" & i] />
    <cfset thisEnhance = form["enhance" & i] />
    <!---- more logic here --->
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will try that again!

Comment: how would u deal with the possibility when a variable is undefined though? I tried using `isDefined` but is not working.

Comment: Make a new question and have that code a part of the question

Comment: Inside the loop you can use either `IsDefined("FORM.amplify"& i)` or `structKeyExists(FORM, "amplify"& i)`. I would recommend `structKeyExist`, as it is a little more accurate. (Edit: If that does not answer your question, please open a new thread).

Comment: This approach works well for textboxes and such, but for checkboxes, having all the fieldnames the same with a list of values is easier to work with, for me anyways.

Comment: @DanBracuk How would you know what value was for what survey (based on OP example). If 'amplify' is checked for 2nd survey, but not the first, how will you know?

Comment: Give each checkbox a different value.  If no boxes are checked, you do not receive a form field at all.  Otherwise, you get a comma delimted list of the values of the checked boxes.

Comment: *RE: having all the fieldnames the same with a list of values is easier to work with*  All depends on the usage. When you need to link or group the selected values with other field(s), then dynamic names may be a better choice. However, for a single field option (like "delete all"), then same name/different value is better.