# ColdFusion Insert multiple form fields with one submit

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sql-insert

**Summary:**

I have a CFC that successfully inserts a single set of form fields into a database table. Now I want to modify it to insert multiple records, but am getting an error when I try to process the dynamic form field names.

**Detail:**

I have (5) form fields that need to be inserted in to the db at the same time, as different rows. So I looped and incremented the field number. I created 5 static rows for it to be simple.

```
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="5"> 
 <cfoutput>
    <input name="ITIProgramName#x#" type="text" ..>
    <input name="ITIProgVer#x#" type="text" ..>
  </tr>
 </cfoutput>
 </cfloop>
```

So the result is:

- ITIPROGRAMNAME1, ITIProgVer1
- ITIPROGRAMNAME2, ITIProgVer2
- ITIPROGRAMNAME3, ITIProgVer3
- ...

I tried to insert the fields into the database by looping like so:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="x" >

    <cfquery datasource="ITSReporting" name="InsertQuery">
    INSERT INTO ITIPRO
        (   ServerID,
            ServerName,
            ProgramName,
            CurrentProgVer,
            LastUser,
            UpDone  )
    VALUES
        (   '#Form.ServerID#',
            '#Form.ServerName#',
            '#Form[ITIProgramName#x#]#',
            '#Form[ITIProgVer#x#]#',
            '#CGI.Auth_User#',
            #CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#
            )
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

But it produces the Error

> Invalid CFML construct

I've tried all sorts of things, but cannot find the right syntax. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: <th colspan="2" scope="col" class="footer">ADD ITI PROGRAM TO <cfoutput>#ITSServers.ServerName# </cfoutput></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Program Name</th>
    <th>Install Version</th>
   </tr>
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="5"> 
 <cfoutput>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="ITIProgramName#x#" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" ></td>
    <td><input name="ITIProgVer#x#" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" ></td>
  </tr>
 </cfoutput>
 </cfloop>
 </table>
    <input type="submit" />
 </form>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing variables of a dynamic form - ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951117/accessing-variables-of-a-dynamic-form-coldfusion)

Comment: Not related to your question, but the CreateODBCDateTime function is not necessary.  You can simply pass the value #Now()#, or don't pass anything and use whatever your RDMS has that returns the current date and time.

Comment: I just tried this
 <cfqueryparam value="#Now()#">
but I have an error executing database query. Is it a syntax error again?? What do you think?

Comment: @SofiaA - You need to add a `cfsqltype` to indicate what type of value you are passing. Otherwise, it defaults to char (or string). That is is probably what is causing your error. The [cfsqltypes are database dependent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html). You did not mention yours, but for SQL Server or MySQL, `cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your variable is close but not quite there, you can only double wrap the # if they are in a quote block.

```
'#Form["ITIProgramName#x#"]#'
```

I would also suggest using a cfqueryparam around your variables on sql inserts.

Comment: I knew it was a syntax error I am not familiar with CF. Thanks @jdunham !

Comment: As suggested, always use `cfqueryparam`. It helps protect your db against sql injection. Also, it improves performance when executing the same query multiple times. Also, do not forget to wrap the loop in a `cftransaction` to ensure all of the inserts succeed or fail as one.

Comment: I am working on it now, I am using cfqueryparam, and I read that I could also use a null field. I am trying to insert not null fields in my db but not very successful at this task.

Comment: cfqueryparam has a null attribute you can use.

Comment: I tried null="no" attribute and still inserting null inputs in db. I will create another question. Thanks

Comment: You may want to enable debug output if you haven't yet to see what the query is actually running, and what ColdFusion is attempting to insert. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0d04c-7fe2.html