# ColdFusion how to update multiple records using cfloop

Tags: coldfusion-10

I need help updating multiple record using cfloop -

**UPDATED STATEMENT**:

```
<cfloop list="#form.id#" index="id">
      <cfquery name="Qname" datasource="#datasourceName#" >
        UPDATE TABLENAME
        SET timeIN = <cfqueryparam  value="#('form.timeIN_' & id)#"  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIME" maxlength="8">,
        timeOUT = <cfqueryparam  value="#('form.timeOUT_' & id)#"  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIME" maxlength="8">,  
        dWeek= <cfqueryparam  value="#('form.dWeek_' & id)#"  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="3">,  
        label = <cfqueryparam  value="#('form.label_' & id)#"  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="10">
        WHERE id =#id#   
    </cfquery>
 </cfloop>
```

> **Query result**:

```
    schedule_ID     timeOUT ID  label   timeIN  dWeek
1   8   09:00 PM    147     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    MON
2   8   09:00 PM    148     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    TUE
3   8   09:00 PM    149     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    WED
4   8   09:00 PM    150     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    THU
5   8   06:00 PM    151     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    FRI
6   8   06:00 PM    152     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    SAT
7   8   06:00 AM    153     BREAKFAST   07:30:00    SUN
```

**Form Dump**

**FIELDNAMES**  ID,dWeek_147,label_147,timeIN_147,timeOUT_147,dWeek_148,label_148,timeIN_148,timeOUT_148,dWeek_149,label_149,timeIN_149,timeOUT_149,dWeek_150,label_150,timeIN_150,timeOUT_150,dWeek_151,label_151,timeIN_151,timeOUT_151,dWeek_152,label_152,timeIN_152,timeOUT_152,dWeek_153,label_153,timeIN_153,timeOUT_153,UPDATE

```
----------

ID  147,148,149,150,151,152,153
----------

timeIN_147  07:30:00
timeIN_148  07:30:00
timeIN_149  07:30:00
timeIN_150  07:30:00
timeIN_151  07:30:00
timeIN_152  07:30:00
timeIN_153  09:30:00

----------

timeOUT_147     09:00:00
timeOUT_148     09:00:00
timeOUT_149     09:00:00
timeOUT_150     09:00:00
timeOUT_151     06:00:00
timeOUT_152     06:00:00
timeOUT_153     06:00:00

----------

dWeek_147   MON
dWeek_148   TUE
dWeek_149   WED
dWeek_150   THU
dWeek_151   FRI
dWeek_152   SAT
dWeek_153   SUN

----------

label_147   BREAKFAST
label_148   BREAKFAST
label_149   BREAKFAST
label_150   BREAKFAST
label_151   BREAKFAST
label_152   BREAKFAST
label_153   BREAKFAST
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a brief explanation of what is wrong with the actual results - and what they *should* be instead? Also, the code above would simply insert literal strings. Can you post your real code?

Comment: BTW, the correct syntax for dynamic variable access is `#form[ 'timeIN_' & id ]#`

Comment: Thank you, Leigh - I made the changes and it worked - How can i give you your credit?

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thanks for the offer, but since this is a pretty common question, best to close this as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion Insert multiple form fields with one submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979332/coldfusion-insert-multiple-form-fields-with-one-submit). Ignore the part about INSERT, the relevant piece is how to access dynamically named variables with array notation.