# Coldfusion variables inside variables

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop through the 7 days in a week and insert data into a table. I have the 3 day abbreviation for the week but need to get the listlast values being passed through. it doesn't seem to be working though. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
<cfset dayabbrev = #left(dayofweekasstring(DayOfWeek(firstofweek)), 3)#>
```

In the above variable that would set the 3 character day of week abbreviation like sun, mon, tue etc.

When I insert into the DB I need to get the last part of the form field after the underscore.

```
 ,<cfqueryparam value="#listlast(FORM.#dayabbrev#l, '_')#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
 ,<cfqueryparam value="#listlast(#dayabbrev#u, '_')#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
```

How would I change the form field name dynamically like this and still allow the listlast function to work? In the above example the form fields should be form.sunl and forn.sunu.

Comment: Change `FORM.#dayabbrev#l` to `FORM['#dayabbrev#l']`. Which scope is `#dayabbrev#u` in?

Comment: Thanks! It is also in FORM scope. Works now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing variables of a dynamic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951117/accessing-variables-of-a-dynamic-form)

Answer (score -1):

Need to use the evaluate() function. This will help to print the variable dynamically.

like this

listlast(evaluate('FORM.#dayabbrev#l'), '_')

Comment: While the `evaluate()` method may work in this case it is highly discouraged to use that method. It is known to have performance and security issues. Using bracket notation is preferred (as mentioned in the other comments). [evaluate documentation](https://cfdocs.org/evaluate)